# How to tell if ajax request was cancelled by form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I've added ajax calls that fire when a user leaves a text box to automatically save their text. There is also a save button at the bottom of the page (the save button is still necessary because it permanently archives the document state at that point in time).

The problem is when a user edits a text box and then directly clicks the submit button. The ajax request is made but then the submit request kills it and I get an error. If I don't get a successful response back from the server then I display a message letting the user know there is a problem (long story short, we've had issues with users spending a long time entering data and then for whatever reason it doesn't get submitted and they lose it all).

In the case that they hit the Save button, I don't care that the request is cancelled because the hitting Save is, obviously, going to Save the data anyway. How can I differentiate between an ajax error where connectivity was lost versus one where it was cancelled because the form was submitted?

I tried this:

```
var formIsSubmitting = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        debugger;
        formIsSubmitting = true;
    });
});

function handleError(xmlRequest) {
    debugger;
    if (!formIsSubmitting)
        alert(xmlRequest.status + ' \n\r ' + xmlRequest.statusText + '\n\r' + xmlRequest.responseText);
}
```

This didn't work though. Also it doesn't break on either of the debugger lines so not sure what's up with that either.

EDIT:

Here's what the button looks like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbnSaveP1" runat="server" OnCommand="GoToPage"
    OnClientClick="return validateP1();" CommandName="1" CommandArgument="1" />
```

validateP1 doesn't do anything fancy... just what you'd expect.

Comment: *" Also it doesn't break on either of the debugger lines so not sure what's up with that either."* i would start debugging that first. Do you have a click event on said button?

Comment: It will hit the debugger line in handleError if there is an error from the server... just not if it's this error from submitting the form. I know that IS running handleError because I see the error message (and I've changed the text it displays just to verify since the error itself doesn't say anything and I wanted to make sure it wasn't coming from somewhere else). And I know it IS NOT hitting the method that sets formIsSubmitting to true otherwise it wouldn't show the error.

Comment: *"And I know it IS NOT hitting the method that sets formIsSubmitting to true otherwise it wouldn't show the error"* That's what i meant. It should be, unless your save button is submitting the form in a way that bypasses submit events such as calling `formNode.submit()` directly where `formNode` is the form element, not a jQuery collection.

Comment: Just sort of thinking out loud with the above comment and making sure I share any pertinent details. Going to check on the submit button now to see if it has a click event and what it does if anything...

Comment: @KevinB I know... sorry, there wasn't enough room left for me to finish the whole comment. I'm checking it now :)

Comment: @KevinB Looks like maybe it's not a proper submit but just a post back. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!